# mysql not updating

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

i have a messaging system and it works fine but i have it so when its read it mysql_querys and sets read to 1. so that way in futer you can tell if its opend. it does not update here is the script for viewing the message where its suppose to update. THANKS

```
<?php
session_start();

require "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $touser = $_SESSION['id'];
        }
        elseif (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            header('location: http://www.stat-me.com');
        }

$id = $_GET['id'];
$memberfirstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];


if(!isset($id)) {
    header('location: inbox.php');
}
elseif(isset($id)) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE pms SET read='1' WHERE id='$id'");    


    $grab_pm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE touser = '$touser' AND id = '$id'");

    while($r= mysql_fetch_object($grab_pm)) {    
        $subject = $r->subject;    
        $message = $r->message;    
        $fromuser = $r->fromuser;    
        $datesent = $r->datesent;    
        $read = $r->read;
    }


}


?>
```

Comment: What data types are id and read?

Comment: read is in the database as enum defult set to "0" and when message is opened for the first time its suppose to update to "1" 

id is the id of the message in the database (also in the link it would be stat-me.com/messaging/view.php?ID=X ) that where it gets it from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if the id field is an INT but I'm guessing so, in which case fix the code as follows (remove the single quotes around $id):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pms SET read='1' WHERE id=$id");
$grab_pm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE touser = $touser AND id = $id");
```

Also be sure to escape your GET variables, e.g.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ;
```

**EDIT:** also take single quotes around $touser above

Comment: Ah, I bet touser is an INT too, right?  I'll edit the answer to reflect that.  Also, have you debugged it?  on a test page or development site, echo out your queries to the browser and copy and paste them directly into your database, e.g. using phpMyAdmin -- do you get an error?

Comment: touser is an int but when it gets to that query it works the problem is the line obove its not setting read to 1. and im kinda new to this what do u mean echo the querys.

thanks

Comment: add to your code: echo "UPDATE pms SET read='1' WHERE id=$id"; 
run the page and you'll see the query on the page, then copy and paste that into your database.  Another thought, is to do SET read=1 -- that might work, though I don't know.

Comment: i copyed UPDATE pms SET read='1' WHERE id=18  and put that in and it said:

Error

SQL query:

UPDATE pms SET READ = '1' WHERE id =18

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='1' WHERE id=18' at line 1

Comment: double check the database table definition for read -- what are the ENUM options that are specified?  The value you pass to read needs to match one of those.

Comment: this is what is under read :
enum('0', '1')   utf8_general_ci
this is so weird

Comment: hmm, you might try changing the field name -- "read" is a reserved word per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: okay some progress. it only worked this time when i put it in manually. i dont know why here is the updated code.:

elseif(isset($id)) {

mysql_query("UPDATE pms SET opened=1 WHERE id=$id"); 
mysql_query("SET opened='1' WHERE id=$id"); 
echo "UPDATE pms SET opened='1' WHERE id=$id";

$grab_pm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE touser = $touser AND id = $id");

while($r= mysql_fetch_object($grab_pm)) {

$subject = $r->subject;

$message = $r->message;

$fromuser = $r->fromuser;

$datesent = $r->datesent;

$read = $r->read;

Comment: I LOVE YOU. I GOT IT TO work just missing quotes. you were right about the reserved word never thought of that thank you so much i cant belive you sticked with me all this time. your a hero. and thank i never thught of escaping url. i didnt know you could get attacked like that

Comment: no problem ... btw if this helped you can accept the answer by checking the checkmark.  Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 0):

Change your queries to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pms SET read='1' WHERE id=".$id);
$grab_pm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE touser = ".$touser." AND id = ".$id);
```

INT datatypes come without double quotes, enums depend on their content (so if you inserted '1' and '0' in example, delete the quotes around '1', if otherwise, keep them).